# Create new postgres database from pg_dump plain-text Script

Tags: postgresql

I am tasked with providing a database export that clients can use to recreate & review their data without needing access to our internal system.

I dump and then try to restore the data as follows:

```
pg_dump --create -d dbname -U user -h host.domain.com --schema='(public|custom)' --data-only --column-inserts > output_file.dmp

createdb -d new_dbname 

psql -d new_dbname -f output_file.dmp
```

I am met with errors like this:

```
psql: output_file.dmp:15172: ERROR:  relation "custom.some_table" does not exist
LINE 1: custom.some_table (id, rev, revtype,...
```

I am not sure if this used to work because I inherited this process, but I am able to replicate their errors on our test Linux server and locally on MacOS.

How can I load these dumps successfully?

Comment: It seems like either myself or the client have a lot more work ahead than originally expected. I may need to figure out how to programmatically recreate each relation before the INSERT.

Comment: Maybe a solution could be drawn from https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/96695/279706

Answer (score 0):

That process doesn't make much sense. If you run

```bash
pg_dump --create --data-only --column-inserts dbname
```

The dump will look somewhat like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE dbname;

\c dbname

INSERT INTO tab ...;
...
```

That is, if you then create database `new_dbname`, then restore with

```bash
psql -d new_dbname dumpfile
```

`psql` will connect to `new_dbname`, then run `CREATE DATABASE dbname`, then connect to `dbname` and restore the dump there.

The error you encounter is unclear; I'd have to see the real, complete message. Perhaps a foreign key references a table that was not dumped?

Comment: I see now that the create step is redundant.