# TablePlus: backup and restore DB with circular FK contraints/references

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, pg-dump

After a backup on TablePlus ([documentation](https://docs.tableplus.com/gui-tools/backup-and-restore)) with only the `--format=custom` option, I got the following:

```
Backup database 'postgres'
Dumping...
warning: there are circular foreign-key constraints on this table:
  hypertable
You might not be able to restore the dump without using --disable-triggers or temporarily dropping the constraints.
Consider using a full dump instead of a --data-only dump to avoid this problem.
warning: there are circular foreign-key constraints on this table:
  chunk
You might not be able to restore the dump without using --disable-triggers or temporarily dropping the constraints.
Consider using a full dump instead of a --data-only dump to avoid this problem.
```

[image: backup options]
[image: restore options] (restore)

I did not use the `--data-only` option neither on the backup, nor on the restore (I did try them also, but they fail with the same warnings).

```
Restore database 'postgres'
Restoring...
  while PROCESSING TOC:
  from TOC entry 3199; 0 16598 TABLE DATA metadata postgres
  error: COPY failed for table "metadata": ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "metadata_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (key)=(exported_uuid) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY metadata, line 1
    
Restore database completed
```

There seems to be no `--disable-triggers` option available and the generated dump file is binary and only 10KB.

Is there anything I can do to successfully perform the backup/dump through TablePlus or are [pg_dumpall](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17741/103411) and [pg_restore (question with disable triggers)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96695/restoring-plain-text-pg-dump-with-psql-and-disable-triggers) the only way to go?

Answer (score 1):

I'd call that a bug or a limitation in TablePlus. Complain to them; at least the limitation should be documented.

Obviously TablePlus uses `pg_dump --data-only` under the hood, which prints the warning you see. Since TablePlus doesn't really seem to add much value to `pg_dump`, my suggestion is that you run `pg_dump` directly.